# Convert string to 2 decimal place

Tags: c#

I have a string (confirm to be of decimal expression)
0.4351242134

I want to convert to a string with two decimal place 
0.44

How should I do in C#?

Comment: What should be the result for 0.3? It Should be "0.30" or "0.3"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var probablyDecimalString = "0.4351242134";
decimal value;
if (Decimal.TryParse(probablyDecimalString , out value))
    Console.WriteLine ( value.ToString("0.##") );
else
    Console.WriteLine ("not a Decimal");
```

Comment: Actually if the initial value is a string you need Double.Parse first.

Comment: You especially need to parse it if you want to achieve rounding.

Comment: sorry, I used to see strings only in quote notation. My fault.

Comment: And you don't need TryParse if you know it's a decimal.

Comment: I know it is decimal, but who else knows? I used not to trust to external inputs)

Comment: Here I've string s1="9.00" and I want to output as decimal d1=9.00 How I'll do? I'm on C# MVC3 –

Answer (score 10):

```
var d = decimal.Parse("0.4351242134");
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(d, 2));
```

Comment: Here I've string s1="9.00" and I want to output as decimal d1=9.00 How I'll do? I'm on C# MVC3 –

Answer (score 9):

Well I would do:

```
var d = "0.4351242134";
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(d).ToString("N2"));
```

Comment: Here I've string s1="9.00" and I want to output as decimal d1=9.00 How I'll do? I'm on C# MVC3 –

Comment: @dilipkumar1007 Are you looking for `decimal d1=decimal.Parse(s1);` ?

Comment: @dilipkumar1007 yes because later somewhere you convert decimal to string to display it. And there's where the answer will help you - somewhere you need to do .ToString("N2")

Answer (score 3):

First, you must parse using a culture or you may loose the decimals.
Next, you must have a text result to have a fixed count of decimals.
Finally, you round to two decimals, but `ToString()` can do that for you, thus:

```cs
string amount5 = "2.509"; // should be parsed as 2.51

decimal decimalValue = Decimal.Parse(amount5, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string textValue = decimalValue.ToString("0.00");

// 2.51
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float f = float.Parse("0.4351242134");
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.00}", f));
```

See [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) for string.Format.

Answer (score 2):

```
float myNumber = float.Parse("0.4351242134");
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:f2}", myNumber ));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Would this help

```
double ValBefore= 0.4351242134;
double ValAfter= Math.Round(ValBefore, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //Rounds"up"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToDecimal(Value).ToString("N2")
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.