# Textbox output size

Tags: c#

First of all i am searching for an answer on the web for my question, and i couldn't find anything besides input limiting which is MaxLength property. If there is an answer about this I apologize..

I am having trouble with limiting or formatting the "output" in a textbox - not input (textbox.MaxLength) - ..
For example I calculated some number double type 268,99894642 .. and i want to limit this display size as 5 digits at most, so it will look like 268,99 . How can i do this?

Thanks..

Comment: Try with: `value.ToString("0.##")` and look here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073416/convert-string-to-2-decimal-place

Comment: Here's a helpful guide on formatting numbers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx Maybe you could post some code describing what you've tried so far.

Comment: When you say "limit to five digits," does that mean you only want two decimal places and you're assuming there are three on the left side? Or does that mean you literally just want the first five digits?

Comment: Did you intend the result to be "268,99" or do you want the rounded value "269,00"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're setting the value programatically you can set the string format:

```
textbox1.Text = someValue.ToString("0.00");
```

Another approach would be to use the `NumericUpDown` control (instead of textbox) and set its property `DecimalPlaces`

Comment: thanks very much that answered my question.. i didn't know the usage of tostring in that way..

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
    double d; //say d is the double var you got calculated after whatever process.
    string dFormatted = d.ToString(); //you can add custom formatting to see commas or decimals here.
    TextBox1.Text = dFormatted.Substring(0, Math.Max(5, dFormatted.Length));
```