# Extra zeroes when parsing string to decimal

Tags: c#, .net

I want to parse a `string` entered in a WinForms text box as a `decimal`. These values are then stored in a property in an object. They should parsed to two decimal places, exactly like the following examples:

```
string amount1 = 2; // should be parsed as 2.00
string amount2 = 2.00; // should be parsed as 2.00
string amount3 = 2.5; // should be parsed as 2.50
string amount4 = 2.50; // should be parsed as 2.50
string amount5 = 2.509; // should be parsed as 2.51
```

How to do this? At the moment, I am parsing as follows:

```
decimal decimalValue = Decimal.Parse(stringValue);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073416/convert-string-to-2-decimal-place

Comment: Any what is the problem you encounter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two operations, parsing and rounding.

```
decimal decimalValue = Math.Round(Decimal.Parse(stringValue), 2);
```